# Can you insert at position 0 in a List<MyObject>?

Tags: c#, collections

I need to insert an object at the beginning of a collection.

My colleciton is of type List

How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure can; for example a generic List of strings:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Insert(0, "NewString");
```

Comment: should probably include that this will insert at 0, and move everything else down the list. (necro comment, sorry)

Answer (score 16):

You can use the Insert method.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "B", "C", "D" };
strings.Insert(0, "A");
```

MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Inserting an item at index 0 will place the inserted object at the beginning of the list and the other items will be shifted up by one.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method

```
myList.Insert(0, [item to insert])
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to expand a little on the other comments:

### general answer

You can insert an Element at position 0 (or any given position) of a list with the following code:

```
List<int> myList= new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    // 0 is the index where you want to insert, i is myobject
    myList.Insert(0,i);
}
```

### performance considerations

List operations are one of the main performance hits of an application.

Inserting in a list comes at a caviat of performance.
Whenever you need to Insert, other elements need to be shifted.
`The longer your existing list is, the slower it gets.`

The example insert function from above takes 42 seconds (on my laptop).

The following function takes ~7ms in comparison.

```
List<int> myList= new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    myList.Add(i);
}
```

if you want to test around a little, you can use something like the following simple setups:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch1.Start();
// function1 to test
List<int> test = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    // 0 is the index where you want to insert, i is myobject
    test.Insert(0,i);
}
int[] testArray = test.ToArray();
stopWatch1.Stop();

Stopwatch stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch2.Start();
// function 2 to test
List<int> test2 = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    test2.Add(i);
}
test2.Reverse();
int[] testArra2 = test2.ToArray();
stopWatch2.Stop();
```

### improvements on inserting

if you have many inserts at 0 in a row for a large list, it might be more performant to reverse the list, append all elements (`AddRange(MyObject[]') and then reverse it back.

```
// list with Data
List<int> myList = myData.ToList();
// reverse
myList.Reverse();
// effectively insert at 0
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    myList.Add(i);
}
// reverse the list back so that the given order from before is retained
myList.Reverse();
```

almost took no additional time.

### improvements on data processing end

simmilarly, if you currently loop over your list with one of the following functions:

```
// classical for loop
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
    MyObject objectToProcess = myList[i]
    /* do work */
}
// classical foreach loop
foreach(MyObject objectToProcess in myList)
{
    /* do work */
}
```

you might as well use a backwards for-loop to process the list backwards. This negates all performance hits entirely:

```
for(int i = myList.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    MyObject objectToProcess = myList[i]
    /* do work */
}
```