# Sort items in the ListView<>

Tags: listview, javafx-2, javafx

I have a simple code of "registration" of items from a list to a text, is working

```
  final private KeyCombination ENTER           = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER);
  final private KeyCombination ESC             = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ESCAPE);

  final ListView<String> listview = new ListView<>();

    final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setPrefRowCount(4);
    textArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
      public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (ENTER.match(event)) {  
          if (!textArea.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            String selectedItem = listview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedItem != null) {
              if (!selectedItem.equals(textArea.getText())) { 
                listview.getItems().set(listview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), textArea.getText());
                listview.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                textArea.setText("");
                textArea.clear();
              }
            } else { // create a new item
              listview.getItems().add(textArea.getText());
              textArea.setText("");
              textArea.clear();
            }
            event.consume();
          }
        } else if (ESC.match(event)) {  // cancel edit
          textArea.clear();
          listview.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        } 
      }
    });
```

I just wanted to change the house that pushes as registers, for example when this is added an item (item 5) it goes to the bottom of the list.

[image: sample]

I want it to be the first

anyone have any solutions?

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586088/can-you-insert-at-position-0-in-a-listmyobject

Comment: did not help, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add items into any position in the `ListView`:

```
listView.getItems().add(0, "item at first position");
```