# Insert an element into a List at index 0: "Cannot convert"

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I found out how to make a  list, but I can't seem to **insert** new values.

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> snake = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
...
snake.Insert(Tuple.Create(x, y), 0);
```

It creates some errors:
Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'System.Tuple' to 'int'
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Tuple'

What am I to do to allow insertion of  values into index 0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586088/can-you-insert-at-position-0-in-a-listmyobject

Comment: Read the error message closely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consult the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that the method signature for `Insert` looks this:

```
public void Insert(
    int index,
    T item
)
```

You confused the order of arguments in your code. You need to supply the index as the *first* argument:

```
snake.Insert(0, Tuple.Create(x, y));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have messed the insert method - it should be like this:

```
  List<Tuple<int,int>> snake = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    snake.Insert(0, Tuple.Create(x, y));
```

[List.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of insert ist

```
public void Insert(
    int index,
    T item
)
```

In your case:

```
snake.Insert(0, Tuple.Create(x, y));
```